# TinyMCE 4 insert link form fields disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-4

I'm using the [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) gem which uses TinyMCE 4 and I'm loading the `link` plugin and all this is initiated after/in a colorbox popup.

TinyMCE editor is working perfectly but the link button brings up a dialog to add/edit a link, but none of the fields except the *target* are available for editing.

below is the related code:

```
setup_new_message: ->
  tinyMCE.init
    selector: '.tinymce'
    plugins: "textcolor link"
    menubar: false
    toolbar: "formatselect | fontselect | bold italic underline | forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link"
    height: 250

  $(document).on 'focusin', (e) ->
    if $(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

I found the $(document).on 'focusin' in other stackoverflow question/answers but this is not working for me. It does fire the `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` but it is not working as everyone said it would.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer once I narrowed down the actual issue was that I was loading the TinyMCE into a jquery.colorbox popup. Colorbox prevents any type of `focus` event/action to happen outside of its defined container. Where as TinyMCE pops its stuff up through iframes, not actually in the colorbox container.

the fix was simple: in colorbox options set `trapFocus: false` and all works as it should. Understand tho, this means the user can *tab out* of the focused colorbox to elements behind the overlay.

via [John Naegle on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23088104/1313409)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of TinyMCE, the solution would be:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.closest(".mce-window").length || target.closest(".tox-dialog").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        target = null;
    }
});
```

And of course the answer from **[Sparkmasterflex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764553/2592415)**

Answer (score 4):

For anyone putting tinymce inside a Material UI mui Dialog, do:

```
<Dialog disableEnforceFocus={true} ...>
```

Comment: You are a God, a God I said!!!

I've been fighting with this for hours

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE5 and MagnificPopup compatibility:

```
$.magnificPopup.instance._onFocusIn = function( e ) {
    try {
        if( $( e.target ).attr( 'class' ).indexOf( 'tox-' ) >= 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch( e ) {}

    $.magnificPopup.proto._onFocusIn.call( this, e );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem `TineyMce` in `Vuejs`, I was loading `TinyMce` inside a dialog when I was trying to add a link another dialog gets open which the second dialog had no focus. Instead of loading the Editor in a dialog I load that in a component and then link dialog inputs got their focus.

Answer (score 0):

I am using TinyMCE as bundledEditor which has been instructed in the documentation page;
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-pm-bundle/#procedure

[@JohnFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3342930/johnflux)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496304/6653960):

> For anyone putting tinymce inside a Material UI mui Dialog, do:
>
> ```
> <Dialog disableEnforceFocus={true} ...>
> ```

worked fine for me.