# TinyMCE Version 5 - Cannot type in standard popup (e.g. link, media) input fields

Tags: input, backbone.js, popup, tinymce, readonly

I’m migrating TinyMCE from version 4 to 5 within a Backbone environment.  I’ve been able to get most of the editor working in version 5, except for all input fields in popups triggered from the toolbar.  The popup will display, but I cannot enter text. You can see the cursor in the text field, you can tab through the fields, you just can’t type in them.  This happens for all input fields from a popup (e.g. links, table properties, media, etc).

I’ve taken the “tinymce.init” function and tried it in a not Backbone environment, and everything works fine.

I did see some comments on Tiny’s site (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/bootstrap/#usingtinymceinabootstrapdialog) in reference to bootstrap, and thought that I could apply it here, to no avail.  I tried a similar response found here: [TinyMCE 4 insert link form fields disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618361/tinymce-4-insert-link-form-fields-disabled)

Any ideas?